# Wordpress email download plugin shows error message

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins

I'm using Email Before Download wordpress plugin on this page

https://sviluppo.babbasons.com/prova-download/

and this product page

https://sviluppo.babbasons.com/prodotto/ak/

This is the error

"Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /web/htdocs/sviluppo.babbasons.com/home/wp-content/plugins/email-before-download/includes/class-email-before-download-db.php on line 56"

this is the code abstract

```
public function item_exists($data)
{

    //check if item exists and if it needs updated
    $query = $this->db->get_row("SELECT  * FROM $this->item_table WHERE download_id = '" . $data['download_id'] . "'");
    if (count($query) > 0) {
        if ($query->file != $data['file']) {
            $this->db->update($this->item_table,
                array('file' => $data['file']),
                array('id' => $query->id)
            );
        }
        if ($query->title != $data['title']) {
            $this->db->update($this->item_table,
                array('title' => $data['title']),
                array('id' => $query->id)
        );
        }
        return $query->id;
    }
    return false;

}
```

On the product page it's stuck loading

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you